# Using T-SQL For Complicated Search/Filter Of Text In Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am using SQL Server 2005 in my environment.

I have a column where each row contains quite a bit of data regarding some SQL queries. Each row looks like one long row in the database, but when you extract the data from the row, it gets split into multiple rows because it contains carriage returns.

Below is an example of the data from one row of the column split up by the carriage returns. I am trying to figure out a way, so far unsuccessfully, in which I can extract everything that comes after the equal sign on each line that contains "pseudo=", except for leading and trailing spaces.

So on lines that contain "pseudo=", I want everything that comes after the = sign. Then I want to trim the leading and trailing spaces, if any. I also want to maintain the carriage returns at the end of each "pseudo=" line. I then want to store this new string of all the "pseudo=" lines into a new row in a new column.

My SQL is not very strong and this little puzzle has thrown me for a loop. Any help is greatly appreciated. Please note that the column will at most have 500 to 600 rows but there is a bunch of text in there if that matters for anything.

```
0x8A40D34D4BEC294D8934029D569B2BFE
table=ca_discovered_hardware
target_type=1
label=label
typefield=
primarykeyfield=dis_hw_uuid
secondarykeyfield=domain_uuid
excludeclause=
[Arguments]
Arguments=12
[Argument 1]
type=1
pseudo= ( 
sql=(
valid=1
[Argument 2]
type=11
pseudo=(Link Query '[ES] IPQ: Tokyo (JPN)' using 'default' method)
sql=dis_hw_uuid in ($TARGETLINKSQL$)
valid=1
queryuuid=f8e488a2b34ee24b85db3f8fafd4e9a2
query_name=[ES] IPQ: S&B - Tokyo (JPN)
[Argument 3]
type=1
pseudo= ) 
sql=)
valid=1
[Argument 4]
type=1
pseudo= AND 
sql= AND 
valid=1
[Argument 5]
type=1
pseudo= NOT 
sql= NOT 
valid=1
[Argument 6]
type=1
pseudo= ( 
sql=(
valid=1
[Argument 7]
type=9
pseudo=(Current Server = 'APTOPRK01CIGE')
sql=ca_discovered_hardware.dis_hw_uuid in (SELECT object_uuid FROM ca_agent WHERE server_uuid IN (SELECT server_uuid FROM ca_server WHERE label='APTOPRK01CIGE'))
valid=1
[Argument 8]
type=1
pseudo= OR 
sql= OR 
valid=1
[Argument 9]
type=11
pseudo=(Link Query '[DM] EXQ: Obsolete Exclude' using 'default' method)
sql=dis_hw_uuid in ($TARGETLINKSQL$)
valid=1
queryuuid=00000000000000000000000000000000
query_name=[DM] EXQ: Obsolete Exclude
[Argument 10]
type=1
pseudo= OR 
sql= OR 
valid=1
[Argument 11]
type=11
pseudo=(Link Query '[DM] EXQ: Server Exclude' using 'default' method)
sql=dis_hw_uuid in ($TARGETLINKSQL$)
valid=1
queryuuid=00000000000000000000000000000000
query_name=[DM] EXQ: Server Exclude
[Argument 12]
type=1
pseudo= ) 
sql=)
valid=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

User defined function `iter_charlist_to_tbl` splits you string to rows with defined delimeter. (taken from [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html))

The `my_convert` function concatenate rows of strings to string

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/565ec/5)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t ( str varchar(max))
go

create function my_convert(@str varchar(max))
returns varchar(max)
as
begin
  declare @p_str varchar(max), @result varchar(max), @delim varchar(2)
  set @delim = char(10)
  set @result = ''

  declare CUR cursor for 
    select right(str, len(str) -7) as result--, str 
    from dbo.iter_charlist_to_tbl(@str, @delim) t
    where str like 'pseudo=%'
  open CUR
  fetch next from CUR into @p_str
  while @@fetch_status = 0
  begin
    set @result = @result + @p_str + char(10)
    fetch next from CUR into @p_str
  end
  close CUR
  deallocate CUR
  return @result
end
go


CREATE FUNCTION iter_charlist_to_tbl
                 (@list      nvarchar(MAX),
                  @delimiter nvarchar(2) = N',')
      RETURNS @tbl TABLE (listpos int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
                          str     varchar(4000)      NOT NULL,
                          nstr    nvarchar(2000)     NOT NULL) AS

BEGIN
   DECLARE @endpos   int,
           @startpos int,
           @textpos  int,
           @chunklen smallint,
           @tmpstr   nvarchar(4000),
           @leftover nvarchar(4000),
           @tmpval   nvarchar(4000)

   SET @textpos = 1
   SET @leftover = ''
   WHILE @textpos <= datalength(@list) / 2
   BEGIN
      SET @chunklen = 4000 - datalength(@leftover) / 2
      SET @tmpstr = @leftover + substring(@list, @textpos, @chunklen)
      SET @textpos = @textpos + @chunklen

      SET @startpos = 0
      SET @endpos = charindex(@delimiter COLLATE Slovenian_BIN2, @tmpstr)

      WHILE @endpos > 0
      BEGIN
         SET @tmpval = ltrim(rtrim(substring(@tmpstr, @startpos + 1,
                                             @endpos - @startpos - 1)))
         INSERT @tbl (str, nstr) VALUES(@tmpval, @tmpval)
         SET @startpos = @endpos
         SET @endpos = charindex(@delimiter COLLATE Slovenian_BIN2,
                                 @tmpstr, @startpos + 1)
      END

      SET @leftover = right(@tmpstr, datalength(@tmpstr) / 2 - @startpos)
   END

   INSERT @tbl(str, nstr) VALUES (ltrim(rtrim(@leftover)), ltrim(rtrim(@leftover)))
   RETURN
END
go

insert t (str) values (
  '0x8A40D34D4BEC294D8934029D569B2BFE
table=ca_discovered_hardware
target_type=1
label=label
typefield=
primarykeyfield=dis_hw_uuid
secondarykeyfield=domain_uuid
excludeclause=
[Arguments]
Arguments=12
[Argument 1]
type=1
pseudo= ( 
sql=(
valid=1
[Argument 2]
type=11
pseudo=(Link Query ''[ES] IPQ: Tokyo (JPN)'' using ''default'' method)
sql=dis_hw_uuid in ($TARGETLINKSQL$)
valid=1
queryuuid=f8e488a2b34ee24b85db3f8fafd4e9a2
query_name=[ES] IPQ: S&B - Tokyo (JPN)
[Argument 3]
type=1
pseudo= ) 
sql=)
valid=1
[Argument 4]
type=1
pseudo= AND 
sql= AND 
valid=1
[Argument 5]
type=1
pseudo= NOT 
sql= NOT 
valid=1
[Argument 6]
type=1
pseudo= ( 
sql=(
valid=1
[Argument 7]
type=9
pseudo=(Current Server = ''APTOPRK01CIGE'')
sql=ca_discovered_hardware.dis_hw_uuid in (SELECT object_uuid FROM ca_agent WHERE server_uuid IN (SELECT server_uuid FROM ca_server WHERE label=''APTOPRK01CIGE''))
valid=1
[Argument 8]
type=1
pseudo= OR 
sql= OR 
valid=1
[Argument 9]
type=11
pseudo=(Link Query ''[DM] EXQ: Obsolete Exclude'' using ''default'' method)
sql=dis_hw_uuid in ($TARGETLINKSQL$)
valid=1
queryuuid=00000000000000000000000000000000
query_name=[DM] EXQ: Obsolete Exclude
[Argument 10]
type=1
pseudo= OR 
sql= OR 
valid=1
[Argument 11]
type=11
pseudo=(Link Query ''[DM] EXQ: Server Exclude'' using ''default'' method)
sql=dis_hw_uuid in ($TARGETLINKSQL$)
valid=1
queryuuid=00000000000000000000000000000000
query_name=[DM] EXQ: Server Exclude
[Argument 12]
type=1
pseudo= ) 
sql=)
valid=1
  ')
```

**Query 1**:

```
-- table result
declare @long varchar(max)
declare @crlf varchar(2) = char(10)
select @long = str from t
select right(str, len(str) -7) as result--, str 
from dbo.iter_charlist_to_tbl(@long, @crlf) t
where str like 'pseudo=%'

/*--string result
select dbo.my_convert(str) from t
*/
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/565ec/5/0)**:

```
|                                                           RESULT |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                                ( |
|      (Link Query '[ES] IPQ: Tokyo (JPN)' using 'default' method) |
|                                                                ) |
|                                                              AND |
|                                                              NOT |
|                                                                ( |
|                               (Current Server = 'APTOPRK01CIGE') |
|                                                               OR |
| (Link Query '[DM] EXQ: Obsolete Exclude' using 'default' method) |
|                                                               OR |
|   (Link Query '[DM] EXQ: Server Exclude' using 'default' method) |
|                                                                ) |
```